# C# Create .icx Calendar file - to remove / cancel appointment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I see a few examples for dynamically CREATING appointments via .icx files, but I have not come across any samples for allowing a user to download a dynamically created .icx file to REMOVE an item from their calendar.  Any suggestions?  I am not sure what attributes would need to match with the existing item  - start/end/ and subject?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551764/how-to-cancel-an-calendar-event-using-ics-files