# How to reschedule event on Windows calendar using .ics file?

Tags: windows, icalendar, schedule

I expected this to be super easy, but it just isn't.
I am trying to prepare .ics files to be attached to an email for events to be added to calendars, I expected to support all major calendars with this approach. I am using icalendar validator for sane checking.

But first problem => icalendar specification in RFCs is super-stupid. I can elaborate on it, but I guess the details are irrelevant.

Second problem is that following the specification, I only made Google calendar to reschedule using `METHOD:PUBLISH` (avoiding `METHOD:REQUEST`), omitting `SEQUENCE` property and sorting the updates based on `DTSTAMP` value. Using this approach, even the Google calendar is not 100% following specification since the events are rescheduled even when actual `DTSTAMP` is the same as largest one received already. But good enough. I would greatly prefer this approach, because of simplicity, but it didn't work for iPhone and Windows calendar.

Final problem, I managed to make it work on iPhone calendar, it can be used with `METHOD:PUBLISH` for rescheduling together with increased `SEQUENCE` property for rescheduling. Better than nothing. But I am still unable to to reschedule event in Windows calendar, how to achieve that? It always creates a new event instead.

So far I am sending something like this as original event:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Travelport//NONSGML GOL Mobile//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Flight 
 from A 
 to B
UID:3d87d036-ad91-4576-b362-6a35296573a9
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTSTART:20240713T153001
DTEND:20240713T153002
DTSTAMP:20231023T120500
LOCATION:airport A, city A
GEO:0;0
DESCRIPTION:Flight 
 from A 
 terminal 1, 
 city A 
 to B 
 terminal 1, 
 city B
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

and something like this as rescheduling event:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Travelport//NONSGML GOL Mobile//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Flight 
 from A 
 to B
UID:3d87d036-ad91-4576-b362-6a35296573a9
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
DTSTART:20240713T154001
DTEND:20240713T154002
DTSTAMP:20231023T120501
LOCATION:airport A, city A
GEO:0;0
DESCRIPTION:Flight 
 from A 
 terminal 1, 
 city A 
 to B 
 terminal 1, 
 city B
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I tried combinations of `PUBLISH`/`REQUEST` `METHOD`s, setting/omitting `SEQUENCE`, `STATUS:TENTATIVE`, adding `ORGANIZER` and I don't see what else should be updated to make it reschedule instead of creating 2 events, which is kind of crazy to me since the objects have same UID. Help!

I tried suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453/icalendar-and-event-updates-not-working-in-outlook) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551764/how-to-cancel-an-calendar-event-using-ics-files) question, but it didn't help.