# fusion-tables input into calendar

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion-table holding a database of my clients. One column is the date of the installation. I'd like to be able to view that information in a google calendar. Does anyone have an easy way to make it happen? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this functionality already exists, but it's not hard to do this yourself.

You could use [one of the client libraries](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/libraries) for Fusion Tables (e.g. [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)) and then just connect to your Fusion Table, get your data and [generate an iCal file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463480/how-can-i-use-php-to-dynamically-publish-an-ical-file-to-be-read-by-google-calen). Then, you can either import the generated file to Google Calendar or just make your script available on a webserver and subscribe to your generated calendar in Google Calendar.

I quickly [put together such a script](https://github.com/odi86/GFTPrototype/blob/master/examples/php/GFTCalendar.php) in PHP (URL: http://gft.rdmr.ch/examples/php/GFTCalendar.php), maybe you can use it as a start or just use your favorite programming language to do it yourself.

Comment: I need a bit more guidance - thanks in advance for your patience. I am a first timer! I uploaded the API libraries to my server along with your sample code. Need some help understanding what I do from here. Thanks!

Comment: In fact I'm ready to pay for your services if you had the time to do it for me!

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. What do you want to know? I think the whole iCal part is not very difficult (depends how many "calendar" feature you want to use, but for simple one-day appointments my script will work). The hard part is to get the data from your Fusion Table. Is it a public or a private table? For private tables you have to have some kind of login (ClientLogin or preferred OAuth). Once you have that setup, all that is left is to write an SQL statement that returns the data you want.

Comment: Sorry - I guess I'm in over my head. Do you know anyone that would be willing to do it for me, for a nominal fee? I have a few more fusion projects I'd love help with if I can find anyone.

Answer (score 0):

As it looked as a cool challenge, I've completed it here:

https://github.com/fontanon/google-fusiontables2calendar

It provides a configuration file making it easier for everybody to put their settings:

```
<?php 

// ::auth config::
// Google Public API Access Key. Don't forget to activate Google API for fusion tables
// Get one and configure access and perms at https://console.developers.google.com
$API_KEY="add yours";

// ::fusion tables config::
// The Fusion Tables ID (find it at fusion tables URL: the docid param)
$TABLE_ID="add yours";

// Name of columns to retrieve from the fusion table, separated by ','.
// Below ones are mandatory for building the calendar, and its position sensitive.
$COL_NAMES="summary,description,start,end,location,url";

// Date format in the fusion table. Examples: d/M/Y, Y-M-d H:i:s, YMdTHisZ ...
$DATE_FORMAT="add yours";

// ::calendar config::
// Name of your calendar
$CAL_NAME="add yours";

// Description of your calendar
$CAL_DESC="add yours";

// Timezone of your calendar. Examples: US/Pacific, Europe/Madrid
$CAL_TZ="add yours";
?>
```