# Subscribe to calendar OS with url that is creating an ical file (PHP)

Tags: php, ios, macos, icalendar

In addition to this toppic:
[How can I use PHP to dynamically publish an ical file to be read by Google Calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463480/how-can-i-use-php-to-dynamically-publish-an-ical-file-to-be-read-by-google-calen)

I have the same question, but then for subscribing to a calendar on OSX en IOS.
I have build an url in php which is creating an Ical-file, the same way as mentioned above in the url.
But when I want to subscribe on OSX then it is saying that the file is not valid.

However when I go to the url in a browser, my ics-file is downloaded and i can add it to the calendar manually.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Double check the URL. I was able to do it on my iphone and ipad.

Comment: Hey artsylar, can you give any code examples? Thanks!

Comment: I've used icalcreator in creating my ics files. http://kigkonsult.se/downloads/index.php#iCalcreator