# How can you create an exportable outlook calendar item from a website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, calendar, outlook, exchange-server

I have a website with a bunch of events on it. Each event has their own unique page.

I'd ideally like to create a link on each event page, that when clicked would create an exchange/outlook calendar item in that user's calendar automatically (either by downloading a file that they must click to add the event, or likewise).

I'm sure this is possible, but can't seem to find any information regarding it.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/ looks promising.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/1463480/205233 offers an approach.