# Turning a PHP file to a XML/ICS file

Tags: php, xml, icalendar

I don't know if I am asking this at the right place or not but I have an interesting question.

So, my work schedule is connected to an XML file that feeds into a PHP file.  I don't have access or can't find what the actual XML file is.

Here is where I am curious about some things.  I would like to be able to either find that XML or find a way that I can create an XML file or ICS file from a php url.  Does that make sense?

Basically, I would like to turn: http://rq4.myprimeportal.com/xml_employee_schedule.php?eid=7794

into an XML or ICS that I can use to grab my work schedule from.  Is this possible?

Can I create a file that pulls the contents from that file into my own file?

I appreciate your help! I hope this all makes sense.  Thank you!

Comment: `<?php header('content-type: text/calendar'); echo 'ics text here'; ?>`. there you go, one php script that outputs ICS.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So, how can I use that? Would I create a new php file on my personal host (bluehost) and paste that? How would I get the contents from my employers php file to load in mine? I am sorry, I'm a little new to coding like this. :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can I create a PHP file that pulls the data from this URL http://rq4.myprimeportal.com/xml_employee_schedule.php?eid=7794 and then in the PHP that I create put in the string that you gave me?

Comment: yes, that's possible.

Comment: `<?php 
header("Content-type: text/xml");
readfile('http://rq4.myprimeportal.com/xml_employee_schedule.php?eid=7794');` - the file is XML already.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you hakre! I was able to create the file with mirrored data! Now, in order for me to output to an ics file, do I add the string that Marc B gave? <?php header('content-type: text/calendar'); echo 'ics text here'; ?>

Comment: I see that my employers original file is text/xml.  After I run the script that HAKRE gave me, how would I then convert it to text/calendar? Maybe I am in way over my head.  Sorry for novice questions everyone.

Comment: Yes, you're asking for everything without dividing. That's too much at once. Either *[How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/367456)* or *[How can I use PHP to dynamically publish an ical file to be read by Google Calendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1463480/367456)* (or similar). Please see these existing questions which are on site already. There is no need to ask the same questions all over again as new postings here, just re-use the existing material that has grown over time.