# Receiving events created when using a custom calendar like iCal

Tags: icalendar

Lets say I've used a library like https://github.com/markuspoerschke/iCal to transform my event data into a ical feed.

This feed is then consumed by a client.

On the client they can see the events in their calendar.

When new events are created on the client, how can I get this information and process it on the web server?

Can this be done with something like ical? Where the client has a callback to the web server with the altered feed, containing the new events data?

Or is this functionality reserved only for apps using the native language to hook into native APIS?

Comment: calendar clients can 'subscribe' to ical feeds, so yes  A can subscribe to B's feed and if A provides a public feed, then B can subscribe to A's feed - try it with say google calendar and some other provider of feeds.   This is not syncing, these are two separate uni-directional feeds, timing of any updates will depend on the applications (may not be realtime).   If you want to 'sync' - 2 way updates then yes you need to do that programmatically with the APIs.

Comment: how does B get the feed url of A. And how can I add this to my own application? What spec is that defined in? iCal?

Comment: Thanks, just read your "feed" - your a legend

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463480/how-can-i-use-php-to-dynamically-publish-an-ical-file-to-be-read-by-google-calen/10491785#10491785

Comment: have you used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV? this seems to be more what I'm looking for?????? @anmari